# Getting the address based on latitude and longitude of multiple points

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to loop through an array of about 10 latitude and longitude values and get the address from them. I created a console application using Xcode and I'm able to loop the file and retrieve the locations, add them to an `NSMutableArray` and pass it to the below function. However the completion handler block never gets called. What could I be doing wrong? Let me know if you need to see any other code at this point. I'm just frustrated and confused and wonder what could it be.

```
void nextGeocodeRequest(int start, NSMutableArray * myLocations)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (int i = start; i < 1; i++)  {
            [ myLocations objectAtIndex:i ];
            double mylong = [[[myLocations objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue ];
            double mylat = [[[myLocations objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
            goal = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: mylat longitude:mylong] ;

            CLGeocoder * geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
            [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:goal completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
                if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
                    placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

                    NSLog(@"this is the state '%@'",placemark.locality);
                    /*
                     self.state = [[State alloc] init];
                     self.state.name = placemark.locality;
                     self.state.code = placemark.administrativeArea;
                     self.state.stateId = 1;
                     self.state.stations = 300;
                     [self.states addObject:self.state];
                     */
                    //[self.tableView reloadData];

                    nextGeocodeRequest(i, myLocations);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
                }
            }];
        } //ends the for
    // return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the executable terminate before the requests complete?

Comment: yes it does wain. though i don't know how to have it wait for the complete handler before exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `run` the current [`NSRunLoop`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html) at the end of your `main` function such that the geocoding connections will be processed. You then need to define how your app will terminate after all of the connections are processed.

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

*(put this at the end of the auto release pool in your main function)*

Currently your app does all of the inline processing, prepares a number of connections with nothing to process them and then simply exits.

Comment: A small example would go a long way buddy. I'm a noob trying to understand. Really appreciate your response.

Comment: thank you eventhough your answer did not directly solve my problem it gave me more then enough to go on and solve my issue. I'm forever thankful for your answer and most appreciative.